# Outer Join on two columns with default value if one column is null

Tags: sql, join, sap-iq

I have two tables - one a transaction table, and the other a look-up table. These tables join on two columns, one of which always has a value, while the other may not.

Sample this

```
transaction table
```

`category | subcategory | marks
A         | 01          | 10
A         | 02          | 20
B         | 03          | 30
B         | 04          | 40
C         | 05          | 50`

```
lookup table
```

`category | subcategory | cut-off
A         |             | 15
A         | 01          | 25
B         | 03          | 35
B         |             | 55
C         |             | 75`

I wish to get the cut-off next to each entry in the `transaction` table by joining the `category` and `subcategory` columns. For cases where `subcategory` does not have an exact match, the record corresponding to `null` needs to be picked.

Desired output format:

```
output format
```

`category | subcategory | marks | cut-off
A         | 01          | 10    | 25
A         | 02          | 20    | 15
B         | 03          | 30    | 35
B         | 04          | 40    | 55
C         | 05          | 50    | 75`

I have been trying to think along the lines of a query like the one below, the problem of course is it doesn't work the way I want it to as it doesn't handle the null case right.

`select t.category, t.subcategory, t.marks, l.cut-off
from transaction t
left outer join lookup l
on t.category = l.category
and t.subcategory = l.subcategory`

Do I need multiple queries (like a `union all` that handles `null` and `not null` separately? Are there options that work with single query?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
SELECT t.category, t.subcategory, t.marks, l.cut-off FROM transaction t left outer join lookup l on t.category = l.category and t.subcategory = ISNULL(l.subcategory, t.subcategory)
```

Comment: this will return duplicate records for cases where the subcategory has a match. In my example, it returns two records for A - 01, and B - 03

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub query (NVL for oracle)

```
SELECT t.category,
  t.subcategory,
  t.marks,
  NVL( 
      (SELECT l.cut_OFF from lookup l where l.category = t.category and l.subcategory = t.subcategory), 
      (SELECT l.cut_OFF from lookup l where l.category = t.category and l.subcategory is null))
FROM transaction t
```

Comment: won't this return multiple values for the second part of the NVL?

Comment: @user1095558 if there is an exact match before for category and subcategory in the first, it returns only 1. If not, the second part assumes category is unique in your lookup table. I have also updated the query in my answer to have a null subcategory

Comment: this approach is good but works only with Oracle. I am on a Sybase IQ system and tried replacing this with COALESCE and ISNULL, however it doesn't appreciate having to deal with expressions inside those two functions. Are there other ways this can be done?

Comment: @user1095558 i have worked almost exclusively on oracle, so can't really help on how this can be done with Sybase. You should also add Sybase as a tag to your question so that it invites the right kind of answers